# Where is this location from the "A 1000 Times" music video?

Tags: where-on-earth

In the [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9FILAkKinQ) of "A 1000 Times" by Hamilton Leithauser + Rostam a woman walks through what I guess is in or near NYC.

I posted a [related question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/which-place-does-west-side-in-hamilton-leithauser-rostams-a-1000-times-re) over in music fans about the lyrics but was not sure about the location in the music video - so where exactly is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1st Avenue and 74th Street, Upper East Side](https://www.google.com/maps/place/1384+1st+Avenue,+New+York,+NY+10021/@40.7691021,-73.9549964,3a,75y,154.58h,94.3t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s7iG1LSyN3lvNx3_7A2dI1A!2e0!7i16384!8i8192!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c258c0dc8fcba9:0x8443d92efe01b220!8m2!3d40.7689541!4d-73.9549501).

At 0:05 in the video you can see the awning of the Best Health Gourmet Deli at 1384 1st Avenue.